# How to abort long running invokeMethod on com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference?

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints, jvmti, jdi

I have my own JDI Debugger which calls the `toString` method on some objects:

```java
com.sun.jdi.ObjectReferenceobject object = ...
ThreadReference threadRef = frameProxy.threadProxy().getThreadReference();
Value value = object.invokeMethod(threadRef, toStringMethod,
                    Collections.EMPTY_LIST, ObjectReference.INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED);
```

The problem is that even if no breakpoints are set inside the toString() method, the invokeMethod never terminates so my debugger hangs. For example this happens when I call this on a `Double` object.

How can I kill the execution of `invokeMethod` after some duration of time?

**Update:** I tried implementing my own `Double` object and put some `System.out.println()` statements at the start and end of the `toString()` method and it seemed that the method is executed just fine but for some reason the debugger doesn't receive the result. Maybe this is a bug in JDI because there are many such bugs, but I am **not** looking for a solution for this, I am just looking for a way to abort the execution of `invokeMethod()` if it takes too much time.

**Update2:** I tried what *ThierryB* was suggesting but I can only invoke `frameProxy.threadProxy().stop(object);` in the manager thread. And the manager thread is blocked because of `invokeMethod()` so it won't execute my command. I tried something like this:

```java
boolean[] isFinished = new boolean[2];
isFinished[0] = false;

DebuggerManagerThreadImpl managerThread = debugProcess.getManagerThread();
new Thread(() - > {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if (!isFinished[0]) {
            System.out.println("Invoked");
            managerThread.invokeCommand(new DebuggerCommand() {
                @Override
                public void action() {
                    try {
                        frameProxy.threadProxy().stop(object);
                    } catch (InvalidTypeException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int threadStatus = frameProxy.threadProxy().status();
                    switch (threadStatus) {
                        case ThreadReference.THREAD_STATUS_RUNNING:
                            System.out.println("The thread is running.");
                            break;
                        case ThreadReference.THREAD_STATUS_ZOMBIE:
                            System.out.println("The thread has been completed.");
                            break;
                        case ThreadReference.THREAD_STATUS_WAIT:
                            System.out.println("The thread is waiting.");
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("The thread is not running / not waiting / not completed : but what is it doing right now ? (a little programmer joke ;) )");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void commandCancelled() {

                }
            });
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();

Value value = object.invokeMethod(threadRef, toStringMethod,
    Collections.EMPTY_LIST, ObjectReference.INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED);

isFinished[0] = true;
```

but `frameProxy.threadProxy().stop(object);` is never executed because the `DebuggerCommand's` `action` method is not called(thread is blocked).

Also this is a Stack trace when my Debugger hangs and I forcefully stop the process:

```
com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException
    at com.jetbrains.jdi.TargetVM.waitForReply(TargetVM.java:317)
    at com.jetbrains.jdi.VirtualMachineImpl.waitForTargetReply(VirtualMachineImpl.java:1170)
    at com.jetbrains.jdi.PacketStream.waitForReply(PacketStream.java:86)
    at com.jetbrains.jdi.JDWP$ObjectReference$InvokeMethod.waitForReply(JDWP.java:4840)
    at com.jetbrains.jdi.ObjectReferenceImpl.invokeMethod(ObjectReferenceImpl.java:413)
```

UPDATE 3: which thread to use to invoke the Method? Currently I am using `frameProxy.threadProxy().getThreadReference();` which works fine most of the time, but is it better to create a separate thread just for invoking methods on objects(along my JDI debugger I also have an instrumentation agent inside the application so I can create a separate thread just for this use case (maybe this will prevent deadlocks?)).

**UPDATE 4:** Currently I am using `SUSPEND_ALL` as suspend policy, would it be better to use `SUSPEND_EVENT_THREAD` instead?

Comment: Be sure to carefully read the description paragraph of the javadoc on the invokeMethod [ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#invokeMethod-com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference-com.sun.jdi.Method-java.util.List-int- ] it details many conditions on which the target vm may encounter a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the interface `ThreadReference` with the method `void stop(ObjectReference throwable)`. The javadoc api tells "Stops this thread with an asynchronous exception.".

```
try {
    com.sun.jdi.ObjectReferenceobject object = ...
    ThreadReference threadRef = frameProxy.threadProxy().getThreadReference();
    frameProxy.threadProxy().stop(object);
    int threadStatus = frameProxy.threadProxy().status();
    switch(threadStatus) {
         case ThreadReference.THREAD_STATUS_RUNNING :
              log.info("The thread is running.");
              break;
         case ThreadReference.THREAD_STATUS_ZOMBIE :
              log.info("The thread has been completed.");
              break;
         case ThreadReference.THREAD_STATUS_WAIT :
              log.info("The thread is waiting.");
              break;
         default :
              log.info("The thread is not running / not waiting / not completed : but what is it doing right now ? (a little programmer joke ;) )");
    }
} catch (ClassNotLoadedException cnle) {
    // log exception, or display a message...
} catch (IncompatibleThreadStateException itse) {
    // log exception, or display a message...
} catch (InvalidTypeException ite) {
    // log exception, or display a message...
}
```

When you are checking your thread status with the `status` method, you can find that values :

- THREAD_STATUS_UNKNOWN
- THREAD_STATUS_ZOMBIE
- THREAD_STATUS_RUNNING
- THREAD_STATUS_SLEEPING
- THREAD_STATUS_MONITOR
- THREAD_STATUS_WAIT
- THREAD_STATUS_NOT_STARTED

Hope you will find a way to do what you need to with the stuff I have provided here.
Examples from [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference&method=stop) or [the following suite test published on the website of Alvin Alexander](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.jdi.tests/tests/org/eclipse/debug/jdi/tests/ThreadReferenceTest.java.shtml) could be helpfull too.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please take a look at my second update. I am sure that I am missing something.